# image display problem with laravel 9 and react Js

Tags: reactjs, laravel

My application works with an API made with laravel 9 in backend and a frontend made with react Js.
I created a form with react to send images to the backend and everything is working fine so far. the images are stored in a public/image/houses folder in the laravel api

Locally I use the laravel 9 function to get a url that allows me to see the image in the browser and it works.
`return $this->sendResponse(url("/images/maisons/{$image->nom}") , 'Image de maison trouvées avec suscces.');`
But once I put the site online, the images are not displayed and laravel returns the error 404|not found
here is my function that allows me to save the images

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    if($request->file('file')){

        $houseId = $request->houseId;
        $file = $request->file('file');

        foreach($file as $actuFile){
            $rand1= rand(0, 200);
            $rand2= rand(0, 200);
            
            $name= $rand1."".time()."".$rand2.'.'.$actuFile->extension();
            $name= str_replace(" ", "",$name);
            $path= $actuFile->move(public_path('images\maisons'), $name);
            

            $save= new Image();
            $save->houseId= $houseId;
            $save->nom= $name;
            $save->path= $path;
            $save->save();
        } 

        return $this->sendResponse('OK', 'image uploadé avec succes');
    }else{
        return $this->sendError("enregistrement de l'image echoué");
    }

}
```

Comment: On your server, does htaccess point towards projects root folder of /public folder?

Comment: Also, are you sure `$actuFile->move()` returns path and not the actual moved file?

Comment: how to make sure that .htacces points to this folder.

Comment: I am sure that `$actuFile->move()`  returns path because in local I manage to access the image with this code

Comment: Okay, so here you are sending response "OK", i suppose it's not the actual code? Where exactly do you get 404? When you call method `store()` ?

Answer (score 0):

Its not issue related to react its the laravel issue
Yesterday i got this same issue with my hosted live site and everything working fine in local server, so i solved this using following method

- laravel stores images in public folder only and not store in nested folders, so instead of storing image in public `images\maisons` you can directly store public `maisons` in this way
- and while retrieving use this location inside `asset('maisons/'.{$image->nom})`

This is worked for me.

so the result is you need to change following things in your code.

```
path= $actuFile->move(public_path('images\maisons'), $name);
```

to

```
path= $actuFile->move(public_path('maisons'), $name);
```

AND

```
(url("/images/maisons/{$image->nom}")
```

to

```
(asset("maisons/{$image->nom}")
```

if its work for you also then welcome in advance.

Comment: Thank you very much Kartik Bharne for taking the time to think about my problem and for making this proposal. Unfortunately I have just made these changes to the way I save the "maisons" and the way I get their images and for the moment the 404 message is still there